# Unable to run Homeworld-sdl in ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: sound, games, pulseaudio

I have a Homeworld GOTY cd. I want to the run game in my linux pc. It is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit dual boot with Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

I have installed the game in windows and it runs fine. As it can be played in linux so I decided to install it in linux.

So I have downloaded homeworld for linux from this [site](http://www.homesource.nekomimicon.net/downloads/stuff_for_testing/index.php?dir=&file=homeworldsdl-Linux-0.5alpha.tar.gz).

After doing neccecary settings [extracting archive to a directory, copying data files from cd and win directory to game directory]
when I typed:

```
./homeworld
```

in my  terminal I got following message displayed and game didn't run.

```
Scanning for newer files in .
Compared 36 filesystem files to main & update bigfiles.
0 files found newer than main bigfile in filesystem.
0 files found newer than update bigfile in filesystem.
Homeworld CRCs = 0x0 (not used) 0x52f110b0 (Homeworld.big's TOC) 0x291050b6
(Update.big's TOC) 0x0 (not used)
Assertion 'p' failed at pulsecore/memblock.c:836, function
pa_mempool_block_size_max(). Aborting.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have allowed the executable execution permission by using `chmod +x homeworld`.

I have searched for this issue in the web but found no solution.

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me to find the the cause of this error and possibly a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the line `Assertion 'p' failed at pulsecore/memblock.c:836, function pa_mempool_block_size_max(). Aborting.` means? Or when does it occur?

Comment: I have downloaded the 0.4 binary archive also. Surprisingly this binary is running, although I am not getting the sound. This release has a _libs_ folder where are some libraries. If I delete this folder then I also get a sound which is annoying, I hear a noise from the speaker and voice speed is very fast.

Comment: Yep --- my answer still stands. Impossible to do anything without a deep knowledge of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

```
Assertion 'p' failed at pulsecore/memblock.c:836, function
pa_mempool_block_size_max(). Aborting.
```

means that the program, in a consistency check, found something that is not supposed to happen. Dazed and confused (cit), it is aborting because it doesn't know how to continue.

This is clearly a bug of the software, which is an alpha release, so [that's not surprising](http://www.homesource.nekomimicon.net/) --- in that page is stated that users at this stage are "brave souls".

Th correct thing to do under the Open Source point of view is to report it to the developers and help them to get it solved. They have a link to a forum in the [homepage](http://www.homesource.nekomimicon.net/).

BTW: at a second glance, it seems that the  last update to the page was in 2007. So it seems that the project is quite abandoned --- or moved to another place.

Comment: Please read my 2nd comment and help me if I could get through this error. I have sent an email to the developer. I have also posted a thread in their forum though at that moment there was no one else visiting the forum except me. Thank you.

Comment: I will also be grateful if you please can tell me whether I can run the program with audio disabled or using something other than pulse audio